# Weird Scenario in Firebase Auth

Tags: android, firebase, caching, firebase-authentication

I'm working on a Android app which use Firebase to authenticate users. I have faced the following scenario which looks like bit weird to me.

I have logged in to my testing app few weeks ago using test account a@a.com. After that I used different accounts but not that a@a.com account.

After few new developments and hundreds of un-installations and re-installations I reinstall the app today as I have to check the feature with a fresh user. I cleared all the user and database from the firebase console. When I installed the app I noticed there is already a user logged in. (`mAuth.getCurrentUser()`)

When I went through the debug console I noticed that it's the user with email a@a.com. Though I have uninstalled the app for hundreds of times that authentication details are still in the firebase cache.

This is a serious issue for the app as it looks like firebase is not clearing the cache when uninstalling the app.

I'm currently using Firebase version `11.4.2` and any help/guideline to solve this issue would be greatly appreciated.

FYI: This is not about database persistence storage. This is an auth cache in firebase itself.

Comment: Firebase is an online database. the online console https://console.firebase.google.com authentication will list all users for your project. Did you uninstall the app from the android device? Are you using a physical device or AVD?

Comment: @Pomagranite I'm using a real device. I have uninstalled the app from the device and even restart the device. But that auth cache is still there.

Comment: did you delete all the users from firebase console?

Comment: @PeterHaddad Yes. I did. started in a clean slate but device still has the cached auth user

Comment: Do you have `android:fullBackupContent="true"` in your manifest? Could be that.

Comment: @SUPERCILEX Nope. I don't have that in my Manifest even after the merge. But I gor android:allowBackup="true"

Comment: I had this issue as well, and it seems to hint at some weird state where there still are credentials available on the device even after uninstalling/clearing all data for the app, which seems to indicate some Firebase caching issue. My case happened when I migrated from my manual authentication flow I implemented on top of Firebase to FirebaseAuthUI, which includes login flows for the providers it supports, and as such I sort of ended up in a weird state where the old credentials I manually took care of in my own implementation lived on within some Firebase cache? Not sure if that makes sense.